# Measure for how long a computer game runs

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python, but I'd like to write a script which could measure how much time I spend with playing a computer game weekly.

For this I'd need to know how can I measure a run time of .exe file of the game. I guess if I wrote a script which is constantly running that could mark the time when  the game client is open, and I would be able to extract the gaming time.

Can someone help me with this, or point me in a different direction if I'm on the wrong track, because I don't really know how to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import time
from time import sleep
processes = subprocess.Popen('tasklist', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

if b"notepad.exe" in processes:
    t0 = time.time()
    while b"notepad.exe" in processes:
        sleep(1)
        processes = subprocess.Popen('tasklist', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    t1 = time.time()
    total_time = t1-t0
    print(total_time)
else:
    print("process does not exist")
```